# Как подписать оси на одном из графике из всего полотна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, визуализация

Как подписать оси х и y для 1-го графика отдельно?

А также, поменять местами оси x и y, чтобы значения возрастов было вместо y. Изначально, специально хотел сделать на данном полотне различные графики.
Возможно ли это, или придется все отдельно?

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2,ncols = 2,figsize=(10,5))
axes[0,0].set_title('гистограмма возраста')
axes[0,0].xlabel = 'Возраст'
axes[0,0].ylabel = 'Кол-во'
axes[0,0].hist(data.Age)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

```
In [12]: for ax in axes.flat:
    ...:     ax.set(xlabel='x-label', ylabel='y-label')

In [13]: plt.tight_layout()
```

---

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> А также поменять местами оси x и y чтобы (возраст был слева)

Вот этого момента я не понял...

Comment: Вероятно, товарищ хочет сделать гистограмму с `orientation='horizontal'`

Comment: @strawdog, так понятнее, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Если вопрос в том как нарисовать горизонтальные гистограммы:

```
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2,ncols = 2,figsize=(10,5))
axes[0,0].set_title('гистограмма возраста')
axes[0,0].xlabel = 'Возраст'
axes[0,0].ylabel = 'Кол-во'
data["Age"].plot.hist(ax=axes[0,0], orientation='horizontal')

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Количество', ylabel='Возраст')

plt.tight_layout()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хотел только одну подписать, но благодаря вам сделал вот так axes[0,0].set(xlabel='Возраст', ylabel='Количество') Спасибо!

Comment: @АлександрГригорьев, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)